# Backbone model validation issue

Tags: javascript, validation, backbone.js

I plan to use http://thedersen.com/projects/backbone-validation/#examples for model/form validation. But model proceed to save while form is not valid. What is wrong?

```
_.extend(Backbone.Model.prototype, Backbone.Validation.mixin);

M=Backbone.Model.extend({
    validation:{
        name:{
            required:true
        }
    },
    url:'foo'
})

m=new M();
m.validate();      //return correct validation error.
m.validationError; // this is null while it should be filled by above error
m.save();          // it communicate with server while the model is not valid
```

Answer (score 0):

Property name has not been set. Try the following code.

```
M = Backbone.Model.extend({
    defaults: {
        name: null
    },
    validation:{
        name:{
            required:true
        }
    },
    url:'foo'
});
```

Comment: Thanks. I hope it work without `defaults` in future version. But yet it leave `validationError` null.

Comment: If you run `m.set('name','test');m.save();m.unset('name);` and then execute `m.save()` it will try to save an invalid model again.

Comment: Ya because you have removed the property again. It's therefore trying to validate on a property that does not exist. Basically the validator needs to know the schema of your model first.

Comment: In the plugin example default is not set for much of elements the http://jsfiddle.net/thedersen/udXL5/

Comment: Check up on the signup method and serialize gist. Currently  `var data = this.$el.serializeObject(); this.model.set(data);` Serializing the attributes into the model. Therefore the attributes exist in the model without having to setup defaults first. It's one way to do it, but I prefer to setup the schema. Therefore I have view of my model and what it is supposed to look like.

Comment: Actually I think it's a flaw in `validate()` implementation. It loop over `attrs` and ignores `validation`. As a result it does not validate `required` fields.

Comment: Do you have any idea regarding empty `validationError`?